# Segmentation fault. Найти строку, содержащую запись самого большого целого числа в десятичной системе

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t 
#include <cstring>  // strrchr 
#include <iostream> 
#include <cctype>

using namespace std; 

// Особое значение координаты -- "не позиция". 

size_t const NPOS = -1; 

// Позиция в тексте: номер строки и колонки (позиция в строке). 

struct Text_position 

{ 
  size_t line = NPOS; // по умолчанию -- не позиция. 
}; 

// Проверка на равенство позиций в тексте (используется в тесте): 

inline bool operator==(Text_position const & a, Text_position const & b) 
{ 
  return a.line == b.line; 
} 


// ...и на неравенство: 

inline bool operator!=(Text_position const & a, Text_position const & b) 
{ 
  return !(a == b); 
} 

// Определить количество строк в тексте. 

size_t text_size(char const * const * text) 
{ 
  size_t size = 0; 
  while (*text++) 
    ++size; 
  return size; 
} 

// Решение задачи: поиск наибольшего числа в тексте. 

Text_position find_the_largest_number(char const * const * text) 
{ 
    size_t number = -1;
    // Идём с начала текста. 
    char max = 0;
    for (size_t line = 0; line < text_size(text); line++)
        for (size_t column = 0; column < strlen(text[line])-1 ; column++)
            if (isdigit(*text[column]))
                if (*text[column] > max)
                {
                    max = *text[column];
                    number = line;
                }
    if (number != -1)
        return {(number)}; 
    return {}; // будет { NPOS } -- символ не найден. 
} 



int test_find_the_largest_number() 
{ 
  char const * const text[] 
  { 

    "A l5ne", 

    "An1ot978her line", 

    "!@#$^!%", 

    "       ", 

    "Abcd 19921344",

    nullptr 

  }; 

  if (find_the_largest_number(text) != Text_position{ 3 }) 
    return 1; 
  if (find_the_largest_number(text) == Text_position{ 2 }) 
    return 2; 
  if (find_the_largest_number(text) != Text_position{ 1 }) 
    return 3; 
  if (find_the_largest_number(text) == Text_position{ 4 }) 
    return 4; 

  return 0; 

} 



int main() 

{ 

  cout << "test find_the_largest_number (should write 0): "; 

  cout << test_find_the_largest_number(); 

  return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде много "странностей", но основная ошибка в том, что в функции поиска вы почему-то обращаетесь к `text[column]`. Это, разумеется, совершенно не правильно. `text` - это массив размера `text_size(text)` (`5` в вашем примере) и обращаться к нему нужно по индексу `line`. У вас же происходит вылет за пределы массива.

Обращение к символам текста, согласно вашей задумке, должно выглядеть как `text[line][column]`. А у вас, по какой-то непонятной причине,  используется `*text[column]`. Почему вдруг `*text[column]`?

Также не понятно, почему цикл `column` итерирует до `strlen(text[line])-1`, а не до `strlen(text[line])`. Почему вдруг `-1`?

Также, в заголовке вопроса сказано, что необходимо найти запись максимального *числа*. Ваш код даже не пытается этого делать. Ваш код ищет максимальную *цифру*.